# Dynamic Memory Allocation C++ use copy constructor or default constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class of type say

```
class Property
{
public:
String a;
int b;
map<string, string> c;
Property();
Property(const Property &prop);
};
```

which is a member of another class as a pointer

```
class Sample
{
  int a;
  string b;
  Property* prop;
  setProperty();
  Sample( prop = NULL);
 ~Sample(
  delete prop;
);
```

My question is that when I create a Sample Object
Sample obj;
and want to initialize the Property* prop;

```
prop = new Property();
prop->a = "random string";
```

//add stuff to map
is doing this and then calling the individual set functions a good way of doing allocation?

or I should declare a Property Object first and then do the complete initialization before dynamically allocating memory?
Declare an object

```
    setProperty()
{
    Property object;
    //initialize it by filling in the string and map and then do within 
    prop = new Property(object);
}
```

Note the above is just incomplete pseudo code.

Comment: A choice between creating a single object, or also creating a second object which only serves to be copied from... which sounds better to you?

Comment: I will suggest you to add the logs in your constructor and check it while you execute the call.

Comment: If existence of `Property` and it's fields are necessary, in my opinion it's better to get them via `Sample` ctor, especially in C++11 you can use move ctor to efficiently construct your object.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an interesting question you have, with quite a simple answer.
In your current situation a copy constructor would be no different than a default constructor when it comes to whether or not the compiler will accept it.
So, to first judge whether you should use a copy constructor or a default constructor we need to take into account 2 factors, performance and memory.

Since the copy constructor and default constructor have barely any difference when it comes to performance, we will skip analysing performance and get to the defining factor, memory.

As TheUndeadFish has stated in the comments, using a copy constructor would be inefficient compared to the default constructor because you would have to stack allocate a whole new, useless object for every time you want to allocate that object in the heap. With a default constructor, you only allocate the object once, then you assign the properties after allocation, which is much more efficient than using a copy constructor.

So, in conclusion, I would personally suggest using a default constructor in your situation instead of a copy constructor.

Comment: In terms of dynamic memory allocation is it better to do the copy, since if not enough memory is available then new fails right away?

Comment: @alexsmith Sorry if I was not clear enough, I'm just saying that using a copy constructor is less **memory efficient** than using the default constructor, because you not only allocate in the heap, but also in the stack.
To be honest, either way it doesn't make much of a difference, just giving you the nit picky answer.